# How to reuse parts of Eloquent builder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to reuse parts of a query in Laravel? For example if I have two queries which share some arbitrarily long section, can I create a function/variable that can be used in place of that section?

**Toy queries:**

```
$a = TableA::join('tableb', 'tablea.bid', '=', tableb.id)
           ->join('talbec', 'tableb.cid', '=', tablec.id)
           ->join('tabled', 'tablec.did', '=', tabled.id)
           ->where('tablea_col', '=', true)->get();

$b = TableA::join('tableb', 'tablea.bid', '=', tableb.id)
           ->join('talbec', 'tableb.cid', '=', tablec.id)
           ->join('tabled', 'tablec.did', '=', tabled.id)
           ->where('tableb_col', '=', true)->get();
```

*I would like something like:*

```
$shared = TableA::join('tableb', 'tablea.bid', '=', tableb.id)
           ->join('talbec', 'tableb.cid', '=', tablec.id)
           ->join('tabled', 'tablec.did', '=', tabled.id);

$a = shared->where('tablea_col', '=', true)->get();

$b = shared->where('tableb_col', '=', true)->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Laravel 8+, you can clone it then reuse as you wish:

```
$shared = TableA::join('tableb', 'tablea.bid', '=', tableb.id)
           ->join('talbec', 'tableb.cid', '=', tablec.id)
           ->join('tabled', 'tablec.did', '=', tabled.id);

$a = $shared->clone()->where('tablea_col', '=', true)->get();

$b = shared->clone()->where('tableb_col', '=', true)->get();
```

before Laravel 8, use

```
$a = clone $shared;
$b = clone $shared;
$a = $a->where('tablea_col', '=', true)->get();
$b = $b->where('tableb_col', '=', true)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [a scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes) for this:

```
function scopeWithBCandD($query) {
    $query->join('tableb', 'tablea.bid', '=', 'tableb.id')
      ->join('talbec', 'tableb.cid', '=', 'tablec.id')
      ->join('tabled', 'tablec.did', '=', 'tabled.id');   
}
```

Which would permit:

```
TableA::withBCandD()->where('tablea_col', true)->get();
TableA::withBCandD()->where('tableb_col', true)->get();
```